# jquery cycle: Showing half og the next and previous slide?

Tags: jquery, gallery, cycle

I am trying to create an image slider (with a header and description text for each image) with the jQuery cycle plugin. The basics are pretty straightforward and working. But I want to show half the previous and next image (only the image, not the header and text) from the current slide.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a straightforward answer to your question, but before you end up in hours of trying to modify an existing plugin to do things it wasn't intended to do, i found out it is usually faster and more inspiring to use jQuery to create your own slider.